# Azure Data Factory - How do I iterate through records in a CSV file using a ForEach loop

Tags: azure, csv, azure-data-factory

What I am trying to achieve:

- I have a CSV (FlattenedListDocument.csv) with the following columns

DocumentKey, DocumentName

Sample values are as follows (there are approximately 240,000 rows in this CSV file):

12212, Hitch Hikers Guide to the Galaxy
12233, MoneyBall

- I have to create a JSON file for each of the rows in the CSV file that will be used by another utility (one file per row).
- I am stuck with how to push the values inside the CSV table to a ForEach activity to get it to loop iteratively through the CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really interesting problem to solve in Data Factory. The only option I see is to have a Data Flow with a Sink partition that outputs files based on a Derived Column.

1. Create a Derived Column that generates the unique blob name. **Be sure to include the folder path**:

[image]

2. In the Sink, under Settings, change the "File name option" to "As data in column", and select the FileName column you created in step 1:

[image]

3. Optional, but in the Sink under "Mapping", remove the FileName column:

[image]
[image]

4. Once finished, you should have this in Blob storage:

[image]

The caveat, of course, is that the file name needs to be unique, so I based it on the first column in your sample (which I named "Id"). I have no idea what performance will be like with 280K files, but this should get the result that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the following that helped me solve the core problem I was having (reading a CSV file and passing the values to a ForEach loop).

Steps 1 and 2 are not part of the core problem but will help anyone else reading this understand how the FlattenedListDocument.csv turned up.

**Overall Schema**

[image]

Step 1: Call web service to obtain the JSON file (XML file as a dataset and a JSON file as a sink).

Step 2: Create a data flow to flatten the file. Create a CSV as a Sink (and partition the sink into 100 equal pieces (to allow for growth of up to 500,000 records in the CSV file).

[image]

Step 3: Perform a look up on the file and obtain it's contents (this will eventually be wrapped up in GetMetadata / ForEach loop that invokes another pipeline to extract the contents of each file).

Step 4: Extract the contents using a ForEach loop (this calls another WebService with the the Name value from the lookup within the pipeline as a parameter).

[image]