# Azure Data Factory: read from csv and copy row by row to a cosmos db

Tags: azure, csv, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-data-factory

I'm new to Azure Data Factory. I'm trying to solve the following problem:

1. Read csv file from Azure Blob
2. Parse it **row by row** and dump each row into an existing cosmos db

I am currently looking into a solution that does:

1. Copy data from source (csv) to sink (Azure Storage Table)
2. ForEach activity that parses the table and copies the rows into the db

Is this a correct approach, and if it is, how should I set up the dynamic content of the ForEach activity?

---

**Note:**

I've tried this solution ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63958428/5490188)) but I get an error message saying

```
Reading or replacing offers is not supported for serverless accounts
```

which means that

[CosmosDB Serverless is not currently supported as Sink for the Data flow in Azure Data Factory.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/194453/does-adf-mapping-flows-support-cosmos-db-serverles.html)

Comment: Did you try use look up to get the content in the table and then foreach the row? the expression should like this: `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Lookup + ForEach actives, the Foreach Items should be:

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value
```

Your solution may be hard to achieve that.

Since you have found that Data Flow doesn't support Cosmos DB Serverless, I think you may can ref this tutorial: [Copy Data From Blob Storage To Cosmos DB Using Azure Data Factory](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/copy-data-from-blob-storage-to-cosmos-db-using-azure-data-factory/)

It uses copy active to copy data from a csv file in Blob Storage to Azure Cosmos DB directly.